# Can the assume-unchanged flag be made to persist between pulls?

Tags: git, version-control

When I set - -assume-unchanged on a file in my git repository using update-index the flag gets reset after I perform a pull which contains changes to the file. I can write a simple script to update the flag after I pull but is there a built in method to make the setting of this flag persist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `.git/info/exclude`.  take a look at the [doc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore)

Comment: The issue I have with using /info/exclude is that, as the documentation states, this is meant for changes specific to this repository instance and are not shared. I need this file to be ignored by default in every instance of the repository that is created. Changes to it should only be uploaded under special circumstances. Sorry, I should have said that in the original question statement.

Comment: @capenma `--assume-unchanged` is local to a particular repo as well. The only way I'm aware of to ignore files across repos is `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in method to make the flag persist. You need to do it with a script or just remember to set it after each pull that modifies the file.